# Which meta names are case-sensitive?

Tags: meta-tags, name, case-sensitive

I am the developer of an HTML checking tool. I want to check meta names to make sure they match case-sensitively when it matters. All I've come across so far (according to Google) is that this meta name ("google-site-verification") should be case sensitive as in:

```
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="XXX">
```

That is, you would not want to use this:

```
<meta name="GOOGLE-SITE-verification" content="XXX">
```

Are there any other meta names that are case-sensitive? I'd like to check for this in my tool.

UPDATE: Looks like Microsoft has many more that are case-sensitive, most of which are msapplication-*: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn255024.aspx

Comment: Similarly "verify-v1" is case-sensitive. Reference: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2007/12/answering-more-popular-picks-meta-tags.html

Answer (score 2):

---

Google is a little bit over exact on this to avoid requests on the verification topic. It's the content="" part of the verification meta-tag which has to be case sensitive. Not the name="" part as you post it in your answer. Google verifies with help of this meta tag even if the name-part is NOT written as they provide it. So

`<meta name="goOgle-sIte-verIficatiOn" content="CaseSensitiveStringASGoogleProvidetIt">`

will work fine as does

`<meta name="GOOGLE-SITE-VERIFICATION" content="CaseSensitiveStringASGoogleProvidetIt">`. (I have tested that.)

This is also consistent with their webmaster help: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/79812?hl=en

With the exception of verify, case is generally not important in meta tags. (This is also the official answer to your question, the case in meta-tag-names is generally irrelevant. As it is according to my own experience.)

If your HTML-checking tool should work like Google did, you could generate a warning, but the website should pass your check, even with this "problem" because it still works fine.

As to the `"verify-v1"` name, I'm not sure if this is still a valid method? On the recent official tools and help pages Google only talks about the `google-site-verification` tag...

Comment: FWIW I believe it's the same with other meta-tag verification setups, like those from Yandex and Bing.

Comment: So what you're saying is that the google info on the page you reference about google-site-verification is actually incorrect and the case of google-site-verification actually doesn't matter like the page says it does? I think it may be best to play it safe and check for a case-sensitive match for google-site-verification anyway because the google page seems to make it clear that the name value must case match as well. As for "verify-v1", I think that is an old name but it still appears on some sites.

Answer (score 1):

In HTML5, there are two sets of *metadata names*:

- [standard metadata names](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140731/document-metadata.html#standard-metadata-names), defined in the HTML5 spec
- [other metadata names](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140731/document-metadata.html#other-metadata-names), registered on the WHATWG wiki page [MetaExtensions](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MetaExtensions)

For the standard metadata names, it is required that they are case-insensitive:

> Names are case-insensitive, and must be compared in an [ASCII case-insensitive](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140731/infrastructure.html#ascii-case-insensitive) manner.

For other metadata names, it says:

> The name should not be confusingly similar to any other defined name (e.g. differing only in case).

Note the "should". So registered values *may* be case-sensitive.

Comment: Good point... that "should" statement seems to imply that meta names could be case-sensitive. And I'm on the hunt for the ones that are. Even the ones that seem to be per documentation might not actually be so this is a point of confusion... best to play it safe I suppose, and check the case of these anyway.

Comment: @AlbertWiersch: But even if a registered name `foobar` is defined to be case-insensitive, there is (AFAIK) no *restriction* (only a recommendation) not to register `FooBar` with a totally different meaning. So a formerly case-insensitive value would now be forced to be interpreted case-sensitive, so it can’t be confused with the new value. -- So I assume, unless it is defined to be case-sensitive on this wiki page, you can never be sure, so your tool should probably display only a warning/note (and not an error).

Comment: I doubt there would ever be foobar (case insensitive) registered with FooBar (case sensitive) type situation. I am just looking for very specific names that are defined or documented to be case sensitive, of which there only seem to be 2 so far (even though the practical case-sensitive nature may be questionable). I am currently generating an error for them but the developer could easily change it to a warning if they want, or disregard altogether. I think these errors will rarely happen though, but just in case the program will now find it and bring it to their attention.